# alignment of wikisource books

Tags: css, wikipedia

The text on some pages is aligned "justified" while some pages are "left" aligned.
I will like to know the reason. For e.g. let's read this book...

> My Father As I Recall Him

The text on this page is left aligned (not justfied).

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/My_Father_As_I_Recall_Him/Chapter_4#Img7

But if I click on any page, for e.g. page 99, the text is justified.

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page%3AMy_father_as_I_recall_him_(IA_cu31924013473610).djvu/99

How is the alignment decided on wikisource?
If I need to change the alignment, is that possible?

Comment: It would need the wikisource designers to answer this question accurately, the rest of us can only give opinions/guesses. Just an observation that in columnar layouts text is often left and right justified, and in wider, single column layouts it often isn't but there is of course no rule about this.

Comment: Wikisource pages preserve the formatting of the source document.